# Updating hbar_stack in Bokeh Server

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to update the bars in a Bokeh server application. I am already doing this in a line chart like this:

```
p.line(x="x", y="y1", source=self.source01, line_width=2, line_alpha=1.0
```

via updating the `source`'s dictionary within a function like this:

```
self.source01.data = dict(
x=self.df_update['timestamp_h'],  
y1=self.df_update[dropdown_aux_surp.value])
```

but this does not seem to work for an `hbar_stack` which I create like this:

```
accu_result_Qaux_therm = 0
acc_result_Qaux_el = 0
acc_result_Q45 = 0
acc_result_Q65 = 0
acc_result_Q85 = 0

self.categories = ['Qaux_therm', 'Qaux_el', ' Q45', 'Q65', 'Q85']
self.exports_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(categories=[], Berechnete=[]))
self.exports_dict = {'categories': self.categories ,
                     'Berechnete': [ accu_result_Qaux_therm, acc_result_Qaux_el, acc_result_Q45, acc_result_Q65, acc_result_Q85]}
self.exports_source.data = self.exports_dict

p_1 = figure(y_range=self.categories, plot_height=250, x_range=(-16, 16),
                     title="Kumulierte Jahreswerte",
                     toolbar_location=None)

p_1.hbar_stack(status, y='categories', height=0.9, color='red',
                       source=self.exports_source.data,
                       legend=['Legende'])
```

if try to update the `hbar_stack`'s dict to load new values into the graph, nothing happens:

```
accu_result_Qaux_therm = 10
acc_result_Qaux_el = 20
acc_result_Q45 = 44
acc_result_Q65 = 5
acc_result_Q85 = 6

self.exports_dict = {'categories': self.categories,
                     'Berechnete': [accu_result_Qaux_therm, acc_result_Qaux_el, acc_result_Q45,
                                                    acc_result_Q65, acc_result_Q85]}
self.exports_source.data = self.exports_dict
```

I apologize if this can be achieved more efficiently but I am new to Python and Bokeh and  just need some enlightenment or information if and how I need to update the `hbar_stack` differently.

Answer (score 0):

I am very sorry, I solved this by myself. I overlooked the following:

There is a typo: Instead of

```
p_1.hbar_stack(status, y='categories', height=0.9, color='red',
               source=self.exports_source.data, 
               legend=['Legende'])
```

it needs to read:

```
 p_1.hbar_stack(status, y='categories', height=0.9, color='red',
           source=self.exports_source, 
           legend=['Legende'])
```

I.e. instead of referencing the ColumnDataSource Object `self.exports_source` I had been referencing the dictionary `self.exports_source.data`. Changing this showed the desired result and the graph was updating.